# Is there a security difference between GPG signing a file directly or its SHA512SUM file?

Tags: hash, gnupg, performance

I am about to decide what SHA-512 hash sum and / or GPG verification scheme I will choose.

Let me present you with two options:

1. Signing the 25 GB ~ 23 GiB (one file fit to a Blu-Ray) directly with:

   ```
   $ gpg --local-user <my_gpg_fingerprint> \
         --sign --armor \
         --output       "${backup_file}.xz.enc.asc" \
         --detach-sign  "${backup_file}.xz.enc"
   ```

   which honestly takes a long time even on a higher-end laptop of mine; or
2. Create `SHA512SUM` of that big encrypted file and sing that one with:

   ```
   $ sha512sum --binary "${backup_file}.xz.enc" > \ 
         "${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM"

   $ gpg --local-user <my_gpg_fingerprint> \
         --sign --armor \
         --output       "${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM.asc" \
         --detach-sign  "${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM"
   ```

   which has actually proven to be <strike>way</strike> a little faster.

---

**Please elaborate as to what security implications might the faster version have as a disadvantage to the direct signing the big file.**

---

### Benchmark

```
$ time gpg --personal-digest-preferences sha512 \
    --local-user <my_gpg_fingerprint> \
    --sign --armor \
    --output test_file_23gib_random_data.asc \
    --detach-sign test_file_23gib_random_data
```

result:

```
real    1m25,444s
user    1m17,059s
sys     0m4,728s
```

As opposed to signing the SHA-512 file:

```
$ time sha512sum --binary test_file_23gib_random_data > \
    test_file_23gib_random_data.SHA512SUM
```

result:

```
real    1m7,568s
user    1m2,810s
sys     0m4,567s
```

and signing it in ~ 0.4 seconds.

---

### Final thoughts

So, there is a few seconds difference. Not really a big deal, but noticeable.

I am still interested in your view about the security implications, which this question was originally intended to be about.

---

Hardware:

- Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7577, model number 7577-92774.
- Processor: I have an Intel Kaby Lake CPU: Intel Core i7-7700HQ.
- Storage: NVMe PCI-E drive.

System:

I am on Linux Mint 19.1; based on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Exactly how much faster is `sha512sum` than signing?

Comment: You can’t compare the two methods, a signature can not be forged and checksum can. For download verification or when you can transport the checksum safely you don’t need signatures. Or you can pgp sign the checksum file. Since pgp does not much more than calculating the checksum your binary might not be optimized (or at the end of the hashing your random source was slow)

Comment: @eckes I don't fully understand your comment. I did present you with option 2, which is exactly as you say: "*Or you can pgp sign the checksum file.*". Please explain your idea more in-depth please. Thank you.

Comment: @eckes PGP signs a digest, not the full file. So why can you forge a SHA512 checksum, but not a signature?

Comment: @vidarlo If you want to change a checksumed File you would change it, checksum it and replace the shasum file with the new checksum. If somebody downloads both they won’t notice a mismatch. If the attacker tries to do that with the signature file they can’t because they don’t have the secret key to create a valid signature.

Comment: Yes it’s option 2, I misread your question. If option 2 is faster this means the sha256sum tool uses better Assembly or compiler settings than PGP, internally most work is spent in the same hash algorithm (if you actually configure pgp to use sha512 hash)

Comment: @eckes If the hash is signed, you cannot replace the hash.

Comment: @vidarlo yes I was talking about unsigned files (as i said i misread option 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most signature schemes already require hashing the data as part of the signing operation. Adding another hash before this shouldn't really be necessary (ie this likely indicates a performance issue in `gpg`), but as long as the hash used is at least as strong as the one used for the signature it shouldn't result in a reduction in security.

There is a minor difference in that `sha512sum` will output the filename as well as the hash, so your signature will be over the filename as well as the data.

Note that `gpg` allows you to specify the hash function with `--personal-digest-preferences` or `--digest-algo`, so selecting a different hash may be an alternate solution to your problem.

Comment: I was unable to replicate the performance issue, so it may have to do with the architecture, compilation options, or gpg version used.

Comment: The fact that you're signing over the filename as well as the data could be considered and advantage, right?\

Comment: @MikeOunsworth It certainly could be, but I'm sure there also exist cases where you might want to be able to change the file name. Something to be aware of at least.